# FragmentPagerAdapter isn't updating the view positions when a data member is added or removed

Tags: android, android-fragments

When the FragmentPagerAdapter is first made, everything is fine. When data is added or removed from the adapter at a certain position, though, the views stay in the positions that they were in.

[Here is a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NpNcIt_WnSw) demonstrating the issue in my WIP app, and [here is an APK](http://ge.tt/9jYfwuY/v/0) of my app that you can use to reproduce the problem.
My full code can be viewed at my [GitHub project](https://github.com/Gawdl3y/task-timer/tree/master/android).

Here's my adapter code (also available [here](https://github.com/Gawdl3y/task-timer/blob/master/android/src/com/gawdl3y/android/tasktimer/adapters/TaskListFragmentAdapter.java)):

```
public class TaskListFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private static final String TAG = "TaskListFragmentAdapter";

    public ArrayList<Group> groups;

    /**
     * Fill constructor
     * @param fm The FragmentManager to use
     * @param groups The groups to display
     */
    public TaskListFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<Group> groups) {
        super(fm);
        this.groups = groups;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * Gets the fragment at position
     * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter#getItem(int)
     */
    @Override
    public TaskListFragment getItem(int position) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Getting item " + position);
        return TaskListFragment.newInstance(groups.get(position));
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * Gets the position of a fragment
     * @see android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter#getItemPosition(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object o) {
        TaskListFragment item = (TaskListFragment) o;
        int position = groups.indexOf(item.group);

        if(position >= 0) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Item found at index " + position + ": " + item.group.toString());
            return position;
        } else {
            Log.v(TAG, "Item not found");
            return POSITION_NONE;
        }
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * Gets the count of fragments
     * @see android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter#getCount()
     */
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return groups.size();
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * Gets the title of a fragment
     * @see android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter#getPageTitle(int)
     */
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return groups.get(position).getName();
    }
}
```

The way I am changing the data is simple; I have a `groups` ArrayList in the activity, and it is changed using `groups.add(position, item)`. The activity then simply does:

```
adapter.groups = groups;
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**UPDATE:**

I revised my code a bit, and added proper .equals() methods to groups, and the result has changed a bit.
`getItemPosition` is now being called twice (for positions 1 and 2) when I insert a group at the beginning, and the last two group views seem to be updating correctly. The one added and the original first one, though, are still not updating. I have updated [the APK](http://ge.tt/9jYfwuY/v/0).

Here is the full output from the adapter when a group is inserted at the beginning and the data set is changed:

```
V/TaskListFragmentAdapter(3597): Item found at index 1: com.gawdl3y.android.tasktimer.classes.Group@b3336038
V/TaskListFragmentAdapter(3597): Item found at index 2: com.gawdl3y.android.tasktimer.classes.Group@b330f330
```

That's it.

Comment: nice job on the question! Video + a link to the source really helps. I'll definately have a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved this issue, finally. What I ended up doing in the end was switching from `FragmentPagerAdapter` to a custom version of `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. My resulting code can be seen at my [GitHub project](https://github.com/Gawdl3y/task-timer/tree/master/android/src/com/gawdl3y/android/tasktimer/adapters). The relevant files are [TaskListFragmentAdapter.java](https://github.com/Gawdl3y/task-timer/blob/master/android/src/com/gawdl3y/android/tasktimer/adapters/TaskListFragmentAdapter.java) and [NewFragmentStatePagerAdapter.java](https://github.com/Gawdl3y/task-timer/blob/master/android/src/com/gawdl3y/android/tasktimer/adapters/NewFragmentStatePagerAdapter.java). This custom version was created by UgglyNoodle [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=37990), with modifications by myself.

Answer (score 0):

I just looked in to your sources and I think that the problem is that you should refresh your groups in your tasks after you add a new group.
Let's say that you have 3 groups and on the 1'st you have some of tasks (like on the video). Now you are adding a group before your first group so it goes to position 0 of your list. Now you have 4 groups, and your tasks still have group field set to 0 because they were on the 0 group before you added a new one and you didn't refresh it. So even if ViewPager is recreating your fragments, your tasks are not where you want them to be.

So I think that when you add a new group and you call reorder(groups) you should create a method that will refresh task.group field for all tasks.

Comment: The `group` property on the Task objects is actually the ID of the group, which is unchanging. This isn't used for the ordering of the tasks. In fact, it's not used for anything at all, until I get the database implemented.

Comment: Yeah i didn't read carefully enough, sorry for that. But still it looks that your tasks should be refreshed some way after adding a new group. When you start your app, you get groups and tasks from your service and when you add a group you only get groups, this is only difference I can see. So probably something is wrong(not refreshed) with your group-task connection.

Comment: There's nothing to refresh about the tasks specifically, as they are contained within the Group objects. The `tasks` array that I do have in the activity is also not in use at the moment. :P

Comment: Also, "Getting item" isn't outputted when a group is added at all, which means that the adapter isn't calling getItem to recreate the views.

Comment: "Item not found" is always logged because when you `reorder` categories `position` change but `item.group` has old position so this objects are not equal. You should investigate this and I think you solve your problem then.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of your question, and from my brief reading of your source, I think the issue is that you are calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the `FragmentPagerAdapter` only. However, you also need to notify your `ViewPager` about this change in the data set.

If you are willing to try [ViewPager Indicator library](http://viewpagerindicator.com/), you could also call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the **indicator**. If not, I suggest you look into the code for `TabPageIndicator` in this library to see how it achieves the effect you are looking for.

Comment: I saw that library, and it's what I was originally going to use, until I discovered the existence of `PagerTabStrip`. Also, `notifyDataSetChanged()` doesn't seem exist on the `ViewPager`.

Comment: There is `invalidate()` on the ViewPager, but that doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Sorry .. I think my answer was not clear. `notifyDataSetChanged()` is on the **PageIndicator** object - not on `ViewPager` itself. `TabPageIndicator` implementation might give you clues on what actually needs to be done in the `notifyDataSetChanged()` for things to work as you expect.